# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1 flutter fetch api

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I can't fetch the next address

but I can fetch sequence shipto 0

RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

after some fixes  type 'sting' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

The data in the address will be included in the same set of items.

Please help me I am practicing fetch api

```
List<dynamic> pos = <dynamic>[];
bool isLoading = false;
 @override
void initState() {
super.initState();
this.fetchMos();
 }

 Future fetchMos() async {
var client = http.Client();
String mosUrl =
    ',';
var url = Uri.parse(mosUrl);
var headers = {'Client-Token': ''};
var response = await client.get(url, headers: headers);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  var items = jsonDecode((utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)))['items'];

  setState(() {
    pos = items;
    isLoading = false;
  });
} else {
  setState(() {
    pos = [];
    isLoading = false;
  });
}


                     

                    

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    elevation: 0.0,
  ),
  body: ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      if (pos.length > 0) {
        return _listItem(index);
      } else {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
    },
    itemCount: pos.length + 1,
  ),
  );
 }

_listItem(index) {
return Card(
  child: ListTile(
    leading: const CircleAvatar(
      child: Icon(Icons.emoji_emotions),
    ),
    title: Text(
      pos[index]['addr1'],
      style: const TextStyle(
        fontSize: 17,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
    subtitle: Text(
      pos[index]['shipto'],
    ),
  ),
);
}





{
"items": [
    {
        "custnum": "",
        "name": "",
        "address": [
            {
                "shipto": 0,
                "addr1": "",
                "thanon": "",
                "tambon": "",
                "amphur": "",
                "prov_code": "",
                "province": "",
                "zipcode": "",
                "country": "",
                "contact": "",
                "postcode": ""
            },
            {
               "shipto": 1,
                "addr1": "",
                "thanon": "",
                "tambon": "",
                "amphur": "",
                "prov_code": "",
                "province": "",
                "zipcode": "",
                "country": "",
                "contact": "",
                "postcode": ""
            },
            {
                "shipto": 2,
                "addr1": "",
                "thanon": "",
                "tambon": "",
                "amphur": "",
                "prov_code": "",
                "province": "",
                "zipcode": "",
                "country": "",
                "contact": "",
                "postcode": ""
            },
            {
                "shipto": 3,
                "addr1": "",
                "thanon": "",
                "tambon": "",
                "amphur": "",
                "prov_code": "",
                "province": "",
                "zipcode": "",
                "country": "",
                "contact": "",
                "postcode": ""
            }
        ]
    }
],
"total_records": 1,
"total_pages": 1,
"current_page": 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your variable `pos` does not contain addresses. You should add the following code after `var items = jsonDecode((utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)))['items'];`

```
var addresses = (items[0] as Map<String, dynamic>)['address'] as List;
setState(() {
  pos = addresses;
  loading = false;
});
```

Then in `ListView.builder` change parameter `itemCount` to `pos.length`.

Lastly, you are trying to give integer as parameter to `Text` widget, which only accepts `String`, so change current code to the following.

```
Text(
  pos[index]['shipto'].toString(),
)
```

Remark: Learn about data models and JSON serialization in Dart, don't use map/json, but try using models.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the itemCount of ListView.builder widget, you'll get an index error.

Try changing your code to this

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    elevation: 0.0,
  ),
  body: ListView.builder(
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      if (pos.length > 0) {
        return _listItem(index);
      } else {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
    },
    itemCount: pos.length, // change here
  ),
  );
 }
```